# mesos containerizer - disk quota

Tags: elasticsearch, mesos

I configured mesos containerizer for elasticsearch-scheduler like that:

```
mesos_containerizers: "docker, mesos"
mesos_isolation: "disk/du,filesystem/linux,docker/runtime"
mesos_enforce_container_disk_quota: "true"
mesos_container_disk_watch_interval: "1mins"
mesos_image_providers: "docker"
```

Now I want to run elasticsearch instance in docker with enabled disk limit/quota to ensure that a single container doesn’t go above its allocated storage.
How to setup this limit?

Is it '--resources' parameter which I can setup thru mesos-agent?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has so called [disk-based shard allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html). What you are interested in is the high and low watermark. So as long as the Elasticsearch process only "sees" the allocated disk, it should use it correctly on its own.

Comment: It's written in book "mesos in action":
posix/disk - A storage isolator for Linux that monitors a container’s disk
usage. When combined with the --enforce_container_disk_quota slave configuration option, it can also be used to ensure that a single container doesn’t go above its allocated storage.